# Onion architecture for middle tier/backend services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, soa, onion-architecture

I am currently working on [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) from J.Palermo. I have some trouble in implementing it in my case. Is this architecture appropriate for 'business less' web sites, aka mashup of services ?

**Here is my case :**

We have many backend services (in WCF), each one exposing isolated Business Data (Marketing, Account, Offer, CMS ...). Our many MVC WebSites 'just' consume these services for rendering pages. All business logic is in the service, and web site is limited to presentation logic. There are no db access in the web site. However some business data can be merged to a composite entity for presentation (such as linking a content page to an offer). I think to put this logic under a service layer.

**Edit :**
Should I create a domain model for mapping backend/middle tier service results/actions ? Maybe the Business logic here is just to merge data from different sources ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the business logic is in the WCF services I'd struggle to see the point of a core project with a domain model (what would it do?). I'm assuming you are not adding a layer of business logic on top of these services to combine multiple operations? If not I'd say the onion architecture is not appropriate in this scenario.

Comment: I have some use cases where I need to merge data coming from different business domains, but I think it is more relevant to presentation logic.

Comment: Well it is good practice to keep the controllers thin and avoid putting anything not strictly related to presentation in them, but you could do that with separate service wrapper or helper class, still sounds like the onion architecture would be overkill. We should not slavishly implement a pattern if it is not going to add value.

Comment: obviously, I don't speak about mvc best practices (DI, thin Controllers, Testability...). See edit

Comment: I'd assume you are using Automapper or similar to map view models. If you want to keep it simple I guess you could map straight to the objects from the services. If you see value in mapping to an intermediate entity then maybe that would be a reason to have a domain model. If it were me I'd probably go with the former route to keep things simple. I keep my Automapper code in the UI project as it is a presentation concern to map from view models. On that basis I still don't see the need for an onion architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that WCF is in effect a Domain Service for other applications. In effect you're just breaking up the Onion across multiple applications.